# Update session data when saving mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update express session data in the mongoose save callback. How can I go about accessing (and updating) the session data from within line 4?

```
app.get('/', function(request, response){
  var model = new Model(somedata);
  request.session.ok = "ok";
  model.save(function (err, data) {
    request.session.ok = "won't save";
  });
});

app.get('/path', function(request, response) {
  console.log(request.session.ok);
  // returns 'ok'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send some kind of response. Example:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response){
  var model = new Model(somedata);
  request.session.ok = "ok";
  model.save(function (err, data) {
    request.session.ok = "won't save";
    response.send(200);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: Session data is saved to the session store only once you send a response. express-session actually does this by monkey patching methods like `response.end()` from node core's http library.